# When I use variable (e.g x) how the machine know the address of this variable

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, stack

When I declare a variable like that

```
Int x = 10
```

The value of 10 will be assigned in a certain address (e.g 0x00001) in main memory and when I use x the compiler will use the value which saved in address (0x00001)
And my question here
When I use variable x, how the CPU know the address of x
Which mean how the CPU know that the variable x has a value in the address (0x00001)

Comment: That's what compiler is doing. It translates your C++ code into assembly code understandable by CPU.

Comment: Note that the CPU may have no idea what an `x` is or that one even exists in your code. This is due to the magic of the compiler. Are you asking how the compiler keeps track of what your `x` is and how/when to tell the CPU to load it into the cache for you program to access?

Comment: I'd recommend you research how C++ code is translated into machine language.

Answer (score 3):

> The value of 10 will be assigned in a certain address

Not necessarily. Depending on case, it might never exist in a memory address, but instead only in a CPU register for example. But let's assume for now that it is stored in memory.

> how the CPU know the address of x

The CPU has no knowledge of x. The compiler generates an instruction that tells the CPU to load or store the value from or to the memory address 0x00001. The compiler is what chose the address, so the compiler knows what address it had chosen. This is an abstract view of what happens. It is a bit more complex in reality.

Answer (score 2):

> When I declare a variable like that 
>   `Int x = 10`

The correct syntax in standard C++ would be `int x = 10;`

> The value of 10 will be assigned in a certain address (e.g 0x00001) in main memory

The value 10 will be written to a memory location on the stack, yes.

> and when I use x the compiler will use the value which saved in address (0x00001)

The compiler does not run your code, it *compiles* it from C++ source code into executable machine code. The variable `x` only exists in your source code.* When your program is compiled, the compiler will replace all references to `x` with a memory address, e.g. `0x00001`. The final executable will *only* operate in terms of memory addresses. So the definition `int x = 10;` will become machine code that looks something like `mov 10, 0x00001`. Realistically, `x` will be defined not as an absolute memory location, but as an offset from the base of the current stack frame.

> And my question here When I use variable x, how the CPU know the address of x Which mean how the CPU know that the variable x has a value in the address (0x00001)

The CPU has no idea what a "variable" is, and certainly has no idea that the memory location `0x00001` happened to be called `x` before the program was compiled. All the CPU ever sees is memory addresses.

---

*Compilers can insert additional information like variable names into executables (this is how C++ debuggers work), but this is unrelated to how the CPU executes the program normally.